# Values changed after converting object type column to string column type Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.9

I have two columns in my pandas dataframe

```
Current selling price      New selling price
  0.0374                         0.03927
  0.1154                         0.12117
  0.0424                         0.04452
  0.1154                         0.12117
  0.1062                         0.11151
  0.035                          0.03675
```

Both the column are of type object.  To do some analysis I want to convert them to string type so I used the below code.

```
df['Current selling price'] = df['Current selling price'].astype('string')
df['New selling price'] = df['New selling price'].astype('string')
```

After conversion some of the values in the column changed with long decimal values.

```
 Current selling price           New selling price
   0.0374                        0.039270000000000006
   0.1154                        0.12117000000000001    
   0.0424                        0.044520000000000004
   0.1154                        0.12117000000000001
   0.1062                        0.11151000000000001
   0.035                         0.036750000000000005
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is precision float problem, you can try round values:

```
df['New selling price'] = df['New selling price'].astype(float).round(5).astype('string')
```